# How to delete selected rows (using checkbox) in wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

My WPF DataGrid is:

```
<dg:DataGrid Name="datagrid1"  Grid.RowSpan="1"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">

    <dg:DataGrid.Columns >
        <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                <CheckBox Content=" Slect All" x:Name="headerCheckBox" />
            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
            <dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <CheckBox Name="chkSelectAll" Margin="45 2 0 0"
      IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=headerCheckBox, 
                          Mode=OneWay}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </dg:DataGridTemplateColumn>

    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

Also Dynamicaly I am populating the data to the datgrid.In xaml.cs file I written the below given code for deleting the selected row from the data grid but it throwing the error at line

```
DataGridRow item =(DataGridRow) datagrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(datagrid1.Items[j]);
```

So Please have a look in to the below given code which I written for doing the same.

```
   private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < datagrid1.Items.Count; j++)
        {
            DataGridRow item =(DataGridRow) datagrid1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(datagrid1.Items[j]);
            CheckBox ckb = (CheckBox)GetVisualChild<CheckBox>(item);
            if (ckb.IsChecked.Value)
            {
                DataRowView drv = (DataRowView)datagrid1.Items[j];
               //delete the row- updating to the database
            }
        }
    }
    static T GetVisualChild<T>(Visual parent) where T : Visual
    {
        T child = default(T);
        int numVisuals = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
        for (int i = 0; i < numVisuals; i++)
        {
            Visual v = (Visual)VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
            child = v as T;
            if (child == null)
            {
                child = GetVisualChild<T>(v);
            }
            if (child != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
        return child;
    }
```

Please let me know if am wrong.

Comment: Bind it to an observablecollection and add/remove items from that collection?

Comment: Looking at the visual tree is not the way to go in WPF. You should create a datagrid that binds to viemodels that have your checkbox state.

Comment: @shoe , Visual T works perfectly if am dealing with a single record.. But the problem is with multiple record :(

Comment: @Tsukasa  I dont have any idea on observablecollection  , can any one please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this. Implement an ObservableCollection of your class that inherits INotifyPropertyChanged. INotifyPropertyChanged will be used in case we want to update items in the collection.

First the xaml for the GridView

```
<DataGrid x:Name="gvMain" AutoGenerateColumns="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="300" Width="300"></DataGrid>
```

Our class of items

```
public class MyClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private string firstName { get; set; }
    private string lastName { get; set; }

    public string FirstName
    {
        get 
        {
            return firstName;
        }
        set
        {
            firstName = value;
            PropertyChangedEvent("FirstName");
        }
    }

    public string LastName
    {
        get
        {
            return lastName;
        }
        set
        {
            lastName = value;
            PropertyChangedEvent("LastName");
        }
    }

    private void PropertyChangedEvent(string propertyName)
    {

        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Next the WPF window

```
public ObservableCollection<MyClass> gridData { get; set; }

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    gridData = new ObservableCollection<MyClass>();
    gvMain.ItemsSource = gridData;
}
```

Test to add, change, delete items in the collection

```
private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    gridData.Add(new MyClass() { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Smith"  });
}

private void btnChange_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    gridData[0].FirstName = "Meow Mix";
}

private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //using List to use .ForEach less code to write and looks cleaner to me
    List<MyClass> remove = gridData.Where(x => x.LastName.Equals("Smith")).ToList();
    remove.ForEach(x => gridData.Remove(x));
}
```

Any changes you want to make will be done with gridData.